# spring jdbc suddenly throws class not found error on SingleColumnRowMapper

Tags: spring, maven, spring-jdbc

I have been developing a Spring project about 6 months. This project is built with maven and spring. Suddenly today i discovered that jdbc sections of the code throwing the error below. I made some changes to my web services in the project lately but I did not change any maven configurations or spring configurations since the last time the application worked stable. Where should I start to look for the error?

Any comment is appreciated.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/SingleColumnRowMapper
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.getSingleColumnRowMapper(JdbcTemplate.java:1184)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:744)
    at com.pozitron.bkmtransfer.core.dao.AcsKeyAliasDaoImpl.findRsaPubKeyByBankId(AcsKeyAliasDaoImpl.java:43)
    at com.pozitron.bkmtransfer.services.core.CipherActionImpl.verify(CipherActionImpl.java:97)
    at com.pozitron.bkmtransfer.services.TransferActionImpl.transferMoney(TransferActionImpl.java:67)
    at com.pozitron.bkmtransfer.ws.endpoints.TransferEndPoint.transferMoney(TransferEndPoint.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first make sure that you have this class (jar) on your classpath. If you do then make sure that you have only one version of this class in your classpath. It might be that new jar was included if you changed/added some dependencies.

Also, if you're starting your app from the eclipse then the only thing you might be needing is to do project->clean

P.S. Are you getting this error at compile time or runtime?

Comment: thanks for your valuable input, after i restarted tomcat, the error went away, do you have any clue about that?

Comment: For some reason your jar file was not deployed. I don't know how your are deploying your app (from command line or from IDE). To debug such errors as 'class not found' I always at first check on the tomcat (lib) if the required jar file is present. And if its not then I try to deploy manually with command line building (mvn install). If it works with command line then its clear that the issue is with IDE deployment. For example in eclipse after changes to java classes you have to republish or restart server (in IDE).

Comment: i was using mvn tomcat plugin, and redeploying all the time